# Taking distinct item from list of datapoints

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a list of Datapoints (List).

```
e.g

original list
(1,2)
(2,2)
(1,3)
(3,3)
(4,3)
(2,3)
(5,4)

I want a output list as

(1,2)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(4,3)
(5,4)
or

(1,3)
(3,3)
(4,3)
(2,3)
(5,4)
```

i.e I want to remove all the other points where X value duplicates.

One approach that I have is to loop through all the point and take the current point x value and compare it with rest of the list if it equals other points X value then remove that value.

How will I do that using LINQ or some extension method(Distinct)

Comment: could you show how you have them stored in your List now? ie, is it a List<string> or maybe List<dictionary<int, int>> ?

Comment: DataPoint is class in System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting. So its List<DataPoint>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with LINQ would be to group points by their X-coordinates, and then pick some arbitrary item from *each* group to produce the output.

```
var filtered = myList.GroupBy(point => point.XValue) // point's bucket depends on its X
                     .Select(group => group.First()) //pick first item from each bucket
                     .ToList();
```

EDIT: A simple way of doing it without LINQ:

```
var pointsByXCoord = new Dictionary<double, DataPoint>();

foreach(var point in myList)
   pointsByXCoord[point.XValue] = point;

var filtered = pointsByXCoord.Values;
```

Comment: Although this has worked for me, will it be a costly operation than a nested foreach??

Comment: @Mohit: In principle, this approach should be much faster than your original suggestion. The only way to find out is to measure, though.

Answer (score 1):

`var enumerable = myList.Distinct()` will return an `IEnumerable<Datapoint>` as long as the Datapoint has implemented the `IEquatable<>` interface.

Here is a nice article on the requirements for the custom type in order to be able to use `Distinct()` extension from LINQ:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/how-to-use-linq-methods-to-compare-objects-of-custom-types)

If you need a list instead of an `IEnumerable` a `ToList()` extension is also provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better solution:

```
var filtered =
myList.GroupBy(point =>
point.XValue.ToString() + "," point.YValue[0].ToString()).Select(group => group.First
()).ToList();
```

because with only xvalue datapoint is not unique.